# Search products by price range, using default block search

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Did someone know what have I to do, to make a possible search products by price range? I know, that Block Layered can filter by it, but it only works in specified category.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to:

1) Add extra input fields next to search box: `from` and `to`. The fields must be inside the form element. You can do this by overriding `blocksearch.tpl` in your theme.

2) Next, you should make override for `classes/Search.php`, method `find()`. You should modify SQL queries at line 252 (`PS 1.6.0.11`). Use `Tools::getValue('from')` to add extra SQL `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much! The last thing that I need to do is to find out a solution for searching without any search query (now it returns error that search query is empty), only price range :)

Comment: I back to this problem. I can't figure how to make a search without search query, only price range.

Comment: You should: inspect what kind of array `::find()` method returns. Then make your own SQL search function (searching by price range only) in `override/classes/Search.php`. Then make an override for `SearchController` (im just guessing here) where the search query is stopped because it is empty. Override the function which stops it, call your own Search function if query is empty, else call normal ::find